# Unable to copy the contents of file to a buffer

Tags: c

```
Operating System Used:Ubuntu 11.04
Compiler Used: GCC
```

Program related files:[Git Hub Link](http://tinyurl.com/6mmzk8a)

I'm trying a implement program which will do a job, same as that of CPP (The C preprocessor) when I compile a .c file.

In this particular code Copy_file_to_buf function not copying the whole file into the buffer.
Acutal size of the is `117406C`,but ftell in the copy_file_to_buf function showing it as `114689`.

> EDIT:
>   There is no data loss when I copied the contents of `dummyfile` to a buffer using same program but I've written copy_file_to_buf program seperately in `temp.c` file.
>
> temp.c

```
#include<stdio.h>
main(int argc,char **argv)
{
    FILE *inputFile;
    int sizeofFile, rc;
    char *source_buf;
    fprintf(stderr, "In Copy_file_to_buf\n");
    sleep(1);

    inputFile=fopen(argv[1],"r");
    if (!inputFile) {
         fprintf(stderr, "Oops, failed to open inputfile \"%s\"\n", argv[1] );
         return NULL;
         }

    fseek(inputFile,0,SEEK_END);
    sizeofFile=ftell(inputFile);

    fseek(inputFile,0,SEEK_SET);
    source_buf=calloc(1,1+sizeofFile);
    rc = fread(source_buf,sizeofFile,1,inputFile);
    /* now check rc */
    fprintf(stderr, "Size of the file=%d; fread returned %d.\n", sizeofFile, rc);
    //sleep(5);
    fclose(inputFile);
    source_buf[sizeofFile] = 0;
    puts(source_buf);
    return source_buf;
}
```

Looks like the fseek() and ftell aren't working as expected for the below code.

```
puts("Copying dummyfile contents");
test_buf=Copy_file_to_buf("dummyfile");
puts(test_buf);
```

> Filename: preprocessor.c

```
#include"myheader.h"

/*   agrv[1]=preprocessor
*    argv[2]=test.c
*
*   Program on PREPROCESSOR
*
*   Steps:
* 1.Removal of comments.
* 2.Inclusion of headerfiles.
* 3.Macro substitution.
*     a.function like arguments
*     b.Stringification
*     c.Concatenation
* 4.Conditional compilation
*     a.#Ifdef
*     b.#If
*     c.#defined
*     d.#Else
*     e.#Elif

*/


int
main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
   char *source_buf,*subBuf,*rmc_buf,*test_buf;
   char **main_header_names,**sub_header_names;
   int main_header_count,sub_header_count;

    source_buf=(char *)Copy_file_to_buf(argv[1]);//...
    rmc_buf=removeComments(source_buf);//...
    main_header_names=(char **)getMainHeaderNames(rmc_buf);//...
    source_buf=(char *)Copy_file_to_buf(argv[1]);//...
    rmc_buf=removeComments(source_buf);//...
    main_header_count=mainHeaderCounter(rmc_buf);//...
    printf("Main Header Count=%d",main_header_count);//...
    includeHeaders(main_header_names,main_header_count);

    subBuf=(char *)Copy_file_to_buf("pre.i");//...
    sub_header_names=(char **)getSubHeadersNames(subBuf);//...

    subBuf=(char *)Copy_file_to_buf("pre.i");//...
    sub_header_count=subHeadersCounter(subBuf);//...

    WriteSubHeadersToFile(sub_header_count,sub_header_names,"dummyfile");//...

    puts("Copying dummyfile contents");

    test_buf=Copy_file_to_buf("dummyfile");
    puts(test_buf);

    /*test_buf=removeComments(test_buf);
    puts(test_buf);
    sub_header_names=(char **)getSubHeadersNames(test_buf);
    test_buf=(char *)Copy_file_to_buf("dummyfile");
    sub_header_count=subHeadersCounter(test_buf);

    WriteSubHeadersToFile(sub_header_count,sub_header_names,"dummyfile2");
    printf("Line:%d   File:%s",__LINE__,__FILE__);
    */

return 0;
}
```

> Filename:CopyFile.c

```
#include"myheader.h"

//Copying input file data into source_buf

char * Copy_file_to_buf(char *fileName)
{
    FILE *inputFile;
    int sizeofFile;
    char *source_buf;
    puts("In Copy_file_to_buf");

    inputFile=fopen(fileName,"r");
    fseek(inputFile,0,2);
    sizeofFile=ftell(inputFile);
    sizeofFile++;
    fseek(inputFile,0,0);
    source_buf=calloc(1,sizeofFile);  
    fread(source_buf,sizeofFile,1,inputFile);
    printf("SIZE OF THE FILE=%d",sizeofFile);
    //sleep(5);
    fclose(inputFile);

    return source_buf;
}
```

Comment: If you happen to be on a Microsoft platform, `fopen(fileName,"rb");` may be needed.

Comment: @wildplasser
I've compiled above code on Unbuntu 11.04.
I did try `fopen(fileName,"rb");` ,but the results were same.

Comment: Please, use the predefined macros (`SEEK_SET`, `SEEK_CUR`, or `SEEK_END`) instead of magic constants.

Comment: Have you inspected the content of `source_buf` to see if the entire text is present? Line-end translations may mean a difference between file-size and data copies to `source_buf`

Comment: @Clifford Yes I did.

Last 30-40 lines were missing in the 'source_buf'.

Comment: In that case it appears that it aborted the read once it determined that there was insufficient data to satisfy your read of `sizeofFile` bytes.  You incremented `sizeofFile` so that it is now the file size plus one.

Answer (score 1):

You are asking `fread` to read one block `sizeofFile` long.  If it cannot read a block that size it will fail and return zero.  Instead you would do better to request `sizeofFile` blocks of 1 byte long.  Then it will report exactly how may bytes it managed to read, which may be fewer than `sizeofFile` for a number of reasons.

```
rc = fread( source_buf, 1, sizeofFile inputFile ) ;
```

In your case it will always be fewer than `sizeofFile` because you previously incremented it, so there never were `sizeofFile` bytes to be read.  You should have read the file size not the buffer size, but the reading multiple blocks of one byte is still preferable in any case.  In fact I would suggest the following changes:

```
sizeofFile = ftell( inputFile ) ;
// REMOVED sizeofFile++ ;
fseek( inputFile, 0, SEEK_SET ) ;
source_buf = calloc( 1, sizeofFile + 1 ) ;       // Don't confuse file size and buffer size here. 
rc = fread( source_buf, 1, sizeofFile, inputFile ) ;  // SWAPPED param 2 and 3
```

It makes sense to use a block size other than 1 if you are reading fixed length records.  If reading a byte stream of arbitrary length, the size should generally be 1, and the count used to determine the amount of data read.

Answer (score 1):

```
char * Copy_file_to_buf(char *fileName)
{
    FILE *inputFile;
    int sizeofFile, rc;
    char *source_buf;
    fprintf(stderr, "In Copy_file_to_buf\n");

    inputFile=fopen(fileName,"r");
    if (!inputFile) {
         fprintf(stderr, "Oops, failed to open inputfile \"%s\"\n", fileName );
         return NULL;
         }

    fseek(inputFile,0,SEEK_END);
    sizeofFile=ftell(inputFile);

    fseek(inputFile,0,SEEK_SET);
    source_buf=calloc(1,1+sizeofFile);
    rc = fread(source_buf,sizeofFile,1,inputFile);
    /* now check rc */
    fprintf(stderr, "SIZE OF THE FILE=%d; fread returned %d.\n", sizeofFile, rc);
    //sleep(5);
    fclose(inputFile);
    source_buf[sizeofFile] = 0;
    return source_buf;
}
```

UPDATE: for testing added main + includes...

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main (int argc, char **argv)

{
char *lutser;

lutser = Copy_file_to_buf(argv[1] );

fprintf (stderr, "Strlen(lutser)=%u\n",  (unsigned) strlen(lutser) );

puts (lutser);
return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 Plasser pis  1008 2012-03-31 15:10 lutsbuf.c
-rwxr-xr-x 1 Plasser pis  8877 2012-03-31 15:11 a.out
Plasser@Pisbak$ ./a.out lutsbuf.c
In Copy_file_to_buf
SIZE OF THE FILE=1008; fread returned 1.
Strlen(lutser)=1008

... 
<contents of file>
...
```

Comment: Look it up in the manual. What does it mean? You are trying to read N+1 bytes from an N sized file. Please reread my answer carefully.

Comment: I'm getting the vale of rc as 1.
`Console Output`:
`SIZE OF THE FILE=114688; fread returned 1.`

Comment: Well, that sounds better. Did you notice that I removed the `sizeofFile++;` line, and changed the calloc to 1+sizeofFile ?

Comment: Credit where credit is due; it was @SlashQB first comment to this that led to my answer. +1

Comment: @Clifford @wildplasser :
I'm still not getting the whole file content in to the buffer.

Last few lines of `dummyfile` are not copied to `source_buf`

Comment: Well it works here. I added a test-driver. Output differs only from lutser.c by a \n (caused by puts()) BTW: You **really** should also check the return from calloc().

Comment: @wildplasser 
Actually the `Copy_file_to_buf` works properly for first four function calls in preprocessor.c program. It is failing(not working as expected) in fifth the call.

Comment: Well: check calloc()s return value than. And: check the returns from fseek(). *end of conversation*

Comment: Step the code in your debugger and see what is different on the fifth call (in the variable state).

Answer (score 1):

Check the return value of `fseek()` (and all other library calls!)

```
if (fseek(inputFile, 0, SEEK_END)) perror("seek to end");
sizeofFile = ftell(inputFile);
if (sizeofFile == -1) perror("ftell");
```

Answer (score 0):

CopyNewFile doesn't close its file.  WriteSubHeadersToFile may not always (hard to follow the flow).  How are you determining the "real" size of the file?

Comment: I've found the 'real' size by opening the file i.e 'dummyfile' with vi editor.